# Error: missing return statement in methods maxDegree and minDegree

Tags: java

**Im getting a compiling error telling me that I'm missing return statements in methods maxDegree and minDegree but I already have them.  I'm not sure how to fix the error.  Can someone please help?*

```
    private int degree( int i )
    {
        return inDegree(i) + outDegree(i); 
    }

    public int maxDegree()
    {
        int max = 0;

        for( int node = 0; node < g.length; node++ )
        {
            if( degree(node) > max ) 
            {
                return degree(node);
            }
        }
    }

    public int minDegree()
    {
        int min = g.length-1;

        for( int node = 0; node < g.length; node++ )
        {
            if( degree(node) < min ) 
            {
                return degree(node);
            }
        }
    }

} // End Graph Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that, in both methods, if you don't enter the `if` statement, you never reach the `return`. So you have to add a `return` at the end of the method, in the case that you never reach the return statement in the `if`.

```
public int maxDegree()
{
    int max = 0;

    for( int node = 0; node < g.length; node++ )
    {
        if( degree(node) > max ) 
        {
            return degree(node);
        }
    }

    // MISSING A RETURN OF A DEFAULT VALUE HERE
}

public int minDegree()
{
    int min = g.length-1;

    for( int node = 0; node < g.length; node++ )
    {
        if( degree(node) < min ) 
        {
            return degree(node);
        }
    }

    // MISSING A RETURN OF A DEFAULT VALUE HERE
}
```

**EDIT** this may be the code you're looking for:

```
public int maxDegree()
{
    int max = degree(g[0]);

    for( int node = 1; node < g.length; node++ )
    {
        if( degree(g[node]) > max ) 
        {
            max = degree(g[node]);
        }
    }

    return max;
}

public int minDegree()
{
    int min = degree(g[0]);

    for( int node = 1; node < g.length; node++ )
    {
        if( degree(g[node]) < min ) 
        {
            min = degree(g[node]);
        }
    }

    return min;
}
```

Comment: @user3814646 No problem, glad it helped. You'll have to decide what is a good default return value, though.

Comment: Yea i got that.  Also I'm not sure if I'm doing my calculations right.  I'm trying to get the maximum/minimum number of edges entering/leaving any single vertex but this isn't right.  Any suggestions?

Comment: @user3814646 I can only stipulate, now knowing exactly the rest of your code. For maxDegree, looks like you should have `int max = degree(g[0]);` (so it's first value). The `for loop should start from 1.` Then, the if condition should be `if (degree(g[node])) > max { max = degree(g[node]); }`.

Comment: @user3814646 I edited my answer, let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Thanks again!!!! I've been staring at this part of the code for an hour.  That worked!

Comment: @user3814646No problem.

Answer (score 0):

You only return if you meet a certain condition.  Return a default after each for loop.